# Responsive Design - image offsets side menu approximately by its height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I have the following code and the following problem:

I have a side menu and a main content. The side menu in Desktop should be on the left, whereas the company content should be on the right. So far so good.

But as soon as I added pictures (which I commented out in this case!) the side menu slided down by the picture's size approximately. It seems only the first picture had this effect, so that's why I commented out here in the example, but of course I would like to have it in production.

I tried putting the picture inside a `span` but that didn't help...

Help is much appreciated.

My snippet:

```css
.side-menu {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 27px;
}
.company-content {
    width: 71%;
    display: inline-grid;
    /*margin-left: 75px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-2 side-menu" style="padding-left: 0px;min-width: 200px;padding-right: 0px;margin-right:50px;padding-left:0px;margin-left:0px;">
      <ul id="menu-map" class="menu" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <li class=""><a href="/Category" aria-current="page">
            <span>Category</span>
          </a></li>        
          <li class=""><a href="/Subcat1" aria-current="page">
            <span><strong>Subcategory 1</strong></span>
          </a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Subcat2" aria-current="page">
            <span>Subcategory 2</span>
          </a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Subcat3" aria-current="page">
            <span>Subcategory 3</span>
          </a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Subcat4" aria-current="page">
            <span>Subcategory 4</span>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="company-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <!-- <span><img src="~/graphics/picture.webp" style="max-width: 350px" /></span> -->
      <b>John Doe</b>
      <br />
      <p>
        <span><b>Text</b></span> <br />
        E-Mail: <span id="email1">loading...</span>
      </p>
      <div class="card" data-person="john">
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="more" style="display: none; color: black"
          ><br />This is a test text. Yup, still testing. <br />
          Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesttiiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnggg.</span>
        <button
          type="button"
          onclick="readMore('test')"
          class="Btn btn btn-dark">
          More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span><img src="~/graphics/picture2.webp" style="max-width: 370px" /></span>
      <br />
      <b>Janet Doe</b>
      <br />
      <p>
        <span><b>Text here</b></span
        ><br />
        E-Mail: <span id="test2335">loading...</span>
      </p>
      <div class="card" data-person="janet">
        <span class="dots Btn" onclick="readMore('test2')"></span>
        <span class="more" style="display: none; color: black">
          This is a test text. Yup, still testing.
          <br />
          Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesttiiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnggg...</span
        >
        <button
          type="button"
          onclick="readMore('test2')"
          class="Btn btn btn-dark"
        >
          More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `width: 100%; display: inline-block;` to the `span` the image and text will be kept in separated "lines".

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <span style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"><img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" style="max-width: 350px" /></span>
      <b>John Doe</b>
      <br>
      <p>
        <span><b>Text</b></span> <br>
        E-Mail: <span id="email1">loading...</span>
      </p>
      <div class="card" data-person="john">
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="more" style="display: none; color: black"><br>This is a test text. Yup, still testing. <br>
          Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesttiiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnggg.</span>
        <button type="button" onclick="readMore('test')" class="Btn btn btn-dark">
          More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"><img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" style="max-width: 370px"></span>
      <br>
      <b>Janet Doe</b>
      <br>
      <p>
        <span><b>Text here</b></span><br>
        E-Mail: <span id="test2335">loading...</span>
      </p>
      <div class="card" data-person="janet">
        <span class="dots Btn" onclick="readMore('test2')"></span>
        <span class="more" style="display: none; color: black">
          This is a test text. Yup, still testing.
          <br>
          Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesttiiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnggg...</span>
        <button type="button" onclick="readMore('test2')" class="Btn btn btn-dark">
          More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Flexbox would work as well.

Comment: Nope, still the same result apparently... I tried setting `!important` as well, didn't help